# Cut string if reached a certain amount of newlines

Tags: php, string

How can I cut a string in PHP if there's a certain amount of newlines? For example, say the string was 10 lines of text, all on a new line, how could I cut that string so that only the first 5 lines showed? I already cut the string to 650 characters, however, I'd also like to be able to cut it, should it reach too many newlines.

Current code that cuts the string if it's above 650 characters:

```
$string = $f2;
$maxLength = 650;

if (strlen($string) > $maxLength) {
    $stringCut = substr($string, 0, $maxLength);
    $string = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')); 
}
$stringchar=htmlspecialchars($string);
echo nl2br($stringchar);
```

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression? Something like ``preg_replace('/(.+?\r?\n){,5}/', '$1', $string);`` or similar.

Comment: I have, and it usually just returns ones or zeros instead of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture first 1-5 lines of multiline input:

```
([^\r\n]*\R){1,5}
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rD7pO0/3)

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match('/([^\r\n]*\R){1,5}/', $input, $m))
   print_r($m);
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it replaced all of my text with either 1 or 0 (I imagine true or false). I appear to be using it wrong. Could you show me how I'd use it? :)

Comment: ok check code in question. It is better to show your attempted code in question if still doesn't work.

Comment: I've been playing about, and unfortunately it doesn't work. Is there not a function that can count how many newlines are in a string?

Comment: It is obvious that you are not reading my commentators and probably not understanding the regex part. I asked you to post your attempted code in question but that you haven't done yet. I have already given you regex and code both in my answer.

Comment: I did exactly what you put. It was honestly returning 1s and 0s rather than actual text

Comment: I think you're probably not aware that preg_match returns 0 or 1 only. Your matched text is returned in matched array `$m` above. Just use code as I suggested and call print_r to see your matched text.

Comment: So in short instead of `print_r($m);` use `echo $m[0];` to get your matched text.

Comment: Ah, right! Well, I used `echo $m[0];` and it's only working on certain strings. Any strings that contain only one line of text don't seem to show at all...

Comment: Check my demi link. Here you can enter 1 line text and see if that matched or not.

Comment: Aha, I managed to fix it! Your answer worked, however if a string had no newlines in it, it would not show the whole string. So I used an if statement to echo `$m` should there be at least one break line. If there were no lines breaks, the code will echo the original, unmatched string

Comment: I am on mobile at present but you can try `{0,5}` in the regex.

Comment: I did try that, but that also didn't work. I guess it's because it was only matching strings that contained `\n` and was dropping the single line strings. I'll put what worked for me in an edit in my question, just in case anyone else sees it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text is in a file and you want to echo it:

```
$file = file('filename.txt');
foreach ($file as $key => $line) {
    if ($key == 6)
        break;
    echo $line;
}
```

If it is a string:

```
$strExploded = explode("\n", $str);

foreach ($strExploded as $key => $line) {
    if ($key == 6)
        break;
    echo $line."\n";
}
```

Comment: @user3779981 So did you get what you were looking for ?

Comment: Unfortunately, although this looked promising, it didn't seem to work for me :(